# What is the default view engine in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

1. In ASP.NET MVC 5, is Razor the default view technology?
2. For example I can choose to use Angular or React or simple html/css/Javascript. So is Razor an alternative to these?
3. In order to use Angular or React, do I need to switch off Razor? Or do they work together?

Comment: MVC runs on the server, React and Angular are SPA frameworks that run on the browser. They aren't view technologies.

Comment: By SPA you mean they can be used only on 1 page?

Comment: Is blazor a view engine?

Answer (score 0):

Razor is the default view engine for MVC 5. It only parses the Razor syntax that you write in the pages. It will not alter your other UI codes.

Angular, React, javascript, html, css codes are not parsed by razor view and runs on the browser only. So you can use Angular, React, html, CSS with regular Razor codes.

Comment: Ok so then what is the alternative to razor? Blazer?

Comment: None. Blazor is an SPA like Angular, React and Vue. What is your actual question? Why are you looking for alternatives to Razor ?

Comment: The question was about Razer not Blazor. Two different thins. One is a View render engine that parses syntax and the other one is a Framework.